# TestComplete different tabs not accessing information within each other in same script

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

So I have a function that looks like this, and ultimately I'm trying to store the button's location information in a different tab inside the same script as the tab the function is in. So for instance in one tab, let's call it GeneralTab, I have all my operations I want to do declared. This is what it looks like.

```
function MyFunction
{
    ThePage.Button.click();
}
```

Pretty simple so far. What I am trying to do is store its location in a different tab within the script. Let's call this tab LocationTab. LocationTab looks like this:

```
var page = LaunchInternetExplorer(url);

function MyPage()
{
    this.Button = page.SomeLocation;
}

ThePage = new MyPage();
```

Here is what is intresting, when I run MyFunction inside of the same tab this works fine. That would look like the following:

```
var page = LaunchInternetExplorer(url);

function MyPage()
{
    this.Button = page.SomeLocation;
}

ThePage = new MyPage();

function MyFunction
{
    ThePage.Button.click();
}
```

But if I try to have them be two different tabs in the same script, I get an error when I try and run `MyFunction()`. It says

> "ThePage is undefined".

What is going on here.

Comment: By "tabs", you you mean "script units/files"? See if this helps: [Calling Routines and Variables Declared in Another Unit](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56539/).

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `//USEUNIT LocationTab` at the top of your GeneralTab script. Check the docs for details: [Calling Routines and Variables Declared in Another Unit](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56539/).